# Maven jersey artifact create a project with no target runtime options

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jersey

I'm trying to build a restful api using a Maven project and tomcat in eclipse.
in the maven project wizard i am using 'org.glassfish.jersey.webapp.archetypes' 'jersey-quickstart-webapp' version 2.26:

[image: maven wizard screenshot]

the problem is - after the project is build, tomcat dosn't recognize the
maven project as a resource:

[image: new server wizard screenshot]

I'v tried to add the target runtime in the project properties but it won't
show up:

[image: project properties window]

How can i correct this? (preferably using a maven)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: I was missing **m2e-wtp - JAX-RX configurator for WTP** plugin in my eclipse:

[image]

To fix this issue:

1) Go to help->install new software

2) Select eclipse repository (I'm using Oxygen this will be different for another eclipse version)

3) Under: **Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development**

select: **m2e-wtp - JAX-RX configurator for WTP**

4) Proceed Installation and restart eclipse

**Note that an existing maven project will not automatically be fixed but a new project will be set correctly**